# Why can't I use a space with foreach statment?

Tags: php, database, mysqli, foreach, prepared-statement

I am building an ASCII binary encoder for my site and when I type a space in my textarea and submit the form it echoes the binary code for null instead of a space. I am using prepared statements to execute my queries. My database has 2 fields, the ASCII character and the binary code for it. My code is splitting the string at each character. Then it checks the database for the bin (binary) field that matches the text in the text area. Why is my code thinking that my space is null and pulling the binary for null out of the database?

Code:

```
<?php
    $decode = $_POST['ascii'];
    require("connection.php");
    $query = "SELECT bin FROM ascii_bin WHERE equivalent = ?";
    $stmt = $connect->prepare($query);
    foreach(str_split($decode) as $equiv){
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $equiv);
        $stmt->bind_result($bin);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->fetch();
        echo $bin;
    }
    $stmt->close();
?>
```

When I enter a space in the textarea **var_dump($_POST['ascii'])** returns this:

`string(1) " "`

Comment: Can you post a dump of the input? `var_dump($_POST['ascii'])` so we can see in detail what you've got?

Comment: Perhaps an issue inside connection.php. I don't see anything wrong here. Unrelated: why wouldn't you just use the `ord()` function?

Comment: Do you have a trim() anywhere?

Comment: Why use a database for this instead of built in pack function? http://us1.php.net/pack

Comment: No @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob

Comment: OK, so can you please echo var_dump($_POST['ascii']); as @Michael Berkowski suggested so that you see the output? You can also echo strlen($_POST['ascii']) if this is easier...should output "1" for a single space

Comment: MySQL ignores trailing spaces in strings. So `"" = " "`.

Comment: See also [How to string-compare for a single space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291098/how-to-string-compare-for-a-single-space/13291179#13291179)

Comment: I echoed both and the `var_dump($_POST['ascii'])` echoes `string(1) " "` and `strlen($_POST['ascii'])` echoes `1`

Comment: Consistent with @Barmar's comment.....the POSTed space by itself is untouched by MySQL until you do something with it in MySQL. See this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728357/can-char-field-retain-trailing-space-character